# Returning XML From a WCF Service

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, datagridview

I am creating a WCF Web Service in which one method (exposed in Service) return data in XML format as given below:

```
    public string QueryDirectoryEntry()
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"c:\" + FILE_NAME);
        return doc.InnerXml;
    }
```

If the client call this method their service return data in XML format , I want to bind this XML in the datagridview control.

The XML data is actually contains the `List<MyStruct>`.

```
class MyStruct
{
  Name..
  ID...
}
```

XML:

```
<root>
  <MyStruct>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </MyStruct>
  <MyStruct>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <ID>2</ID>
  </MyStruct>
</root>
```

**I want that data should be in XML** so that every application can use this data either in C# or Java.

Comment: On re-reading this question, I see that the OP may have thought he _had to_ return XML in order for a Java or other non-.NET application to use it. That is not the case. If he had just returned `List<MyStruct>`, then WCF would have serialized it into XML for him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never return or manipulate XML as a string. Return it as XmlElement instead:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IReturnRealXml {
    [OperationContract]
    XmlElement QueryDirectoryEntry();
}

public class ReturnRealXmlNotStrings : IReturnRealXml {

    public XmlElement QueryDirectoryEntry()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"c:\" + FILE_NAME);
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John for correcting me.. But can you please tell me how can I acheive the above said functionality ?

Comment: I filled it out a bit. Is that better?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response...Thanks for the reply John